# View buttons are not anymore clickable after adding a .xib view as subview

Tags: swift, iphone, view, uiviewcontroller, xib

I have a viewcontroller where a card from below is displayed. I used a .xib view to swipe from the bottom of view controller bu the viewcontroller buttons are not anymore clickable after adding .xib view as subview in the viewcontroller's view even when the .xib view is collapsed. "cardViewController" is the name of .xib view.

```
    var cardViewController:FrenchiasCardViewController!
func setupCard()
{
    // Setup starting and ending card height
    endCardHeight = self.view.frame.height * 0.9
    startCardHeight = self.view.frame.height * 0.08

    // Add Visual Effects View
    visualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView()
    visualEffectView.frame = self.view.frame
    self.view.addSubview(visualEffectView)

    // Add CardViewController xib to the bottom of the screen, clipping bounds so that the corners can be rounded
    cardViewController = FrenchiasCardViewController(nibName:"FrenchiasCardViewController", bundle:nil)
    self.view.addSubview(cardViewController.view)
    cardViewController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.height - startCardHeight, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: endCardHeight)
    cardViewController.view.clipsToBounds = true

    // Add tap and pan recognizers
    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(NewAddressView.handleCardTap(recognzier:)))
    let panGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(NewAddressView.handleCardPan(recognizer:)))

    cardViewController.handleArea.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
    cardViewController.handleArea.addGestureRecognizer(panGestureRecognizer)
}

    let frameAnimator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: duration, dampingRatio: 1) {
            switch state {
            case .expanded:
                // If expanding set popover y to the ending height and blur background
                self.cardViewController.view.frame.origin.y = self.view.frame.height - self.endCardHeight
                self.visualEffectView.effect = UIBlurEffect(style: .dark)

            case .collapsed:
                // If collapsed set popover y to the starting height and remove background blur
                self.cardViewController.view.frame.origin.y = self.view.frame.height - self.startCardHeight

                self.visualEffectView.effect = nil
            }
        }
```

Comment: Try to set the buttons' superview clipToBounds to true and check if you can still see the buttons. This will help you to understand if there is an issue with the superview's frame.

Comment: My buttons are viewable its just they are do not perform any action on tap.

Comment: If clipToBounds is false and the superview's size is smaller, you will be able to see subviews but not interact with them. I have experienced an issue like this in the past and after debugging with the UI Hierarchy debugger, I have found that the superview height was 0. So I saw the buttons but could not interact with them. Also, I would suggest to make sure isuserinteractionenabled is true on the superview.

Comment: @Sam I have tried adding is userinteraction enabled, and also cliptobounds true, but still can't interact with button, textviews on view, the thing is I have used a .xib view and collapse it but then adding .xib view controller views are not interact able anymore

Comment: Try to inspect the views using the UI Hierarchy debugger.